# Song artwork does not appear on album?

Tags: catalina, music

Ever since upgrading to the new Music app on Catalina (or maybe was it when I copied my music in from a backup?) all of my album artwork is not visible on the album views:

[image]

The art is still attached to the individual songs, as evidenced by viewing the song information:

[image]

How do I get this song art (which clearly exists and is available) to show up on the album view?

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not sure exactly why this happened, but I was able to find a solution in via one of Doug's AppleScripts. Once again this man saves my day.

[image]

It is his [*Re-Embed Artwork* script](https://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=mxreembedartwork). It takes quite a while to run, but I can already tell that it is working:

[image]